# I'm trying to install TF2 from steam but it won't allow me to install because i only have 220mb (but i have well over 50 gigs?

Tags: steam

I try to install TF2 but it says i don't have enough space but, I have well over 50GB on my laptop, What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you 100 % sure that you have enough of free space on the partition where /home is located?

Comment: where is /home located?

Comment: Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and run `df -h`. If you have a separate partition for `/home`, it will say that you have a filesystem mounted on `/home`. On that line, check how much available free space it has. If you don't have a separate home partition, then check the amount of free space on the root `/` partition instead.

Comment: Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            975M  799M  176M  82% /
udev            967M  4.0K  967M   1% /dev
tmpfs           390M  796K  390M   1% /run
/dev/sr0        754M  754M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      723M  723M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs           975M   12K  975M   1% /tmp
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            975M  180K  975M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6        43G  2.4G   38G   6% /media/ubuntu/26250761-30fb-44f2-b1eb-4d93315a8ae4
/dev/sda2       176G  134G   42G  77% /media/ubuntu/C87CE2667CE24F2E

Comment: How do I change the amount of memory I allow Linux?

Comment: That's another question. But basically it depends on if you have installed Ubuntu through Wubi or not. If you have installed it normally you can update your partition table with GParted. I don't think it's possible to increase Ubuntu's size if it's installed through Wubi tho. But again, this is another question and don't forget to backup you data before you mess around with partition tables.

Comment: I gave up and returning to Win 7

Answer (score 1):

Look at output of:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You may have smaller size of /home partition. You can resize it through LiveCD and gParted on it. Boot LiveCD, select **Try Ubuntu** and launch gParted. You can modify partitions as you want/need.

**Don´t forget to backup everything on it first**.